# Can RDS (Mysql in my case) endpoint be connected with 2 instances in different availability zones?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What am I trying to achieve?

1.Trying to build a fault-tolerant  WordPress website.

2.Tried installing the webserver on one AZ with Muti-AZ RDS deployment.It was quite successful.

Set up is as follows

AZ-1 Public subnet  - Launched one ec-2 instance, Installed httpd, PHP, PHP-MySQL, WORDPRESS.

AZ-1 Private subnet - Launched a Multi-AZ RDS instance

Problem Encountered:

1. When I Wanted to expand to another availability zone for fault tolerance.
2. Launched another ec-2 instance in different availability zone [AZ-2] and installed httpd, PHP, PHP-MySQL, WORDPRESS
   I **DID NOT** launch an another RDS.I wanted to connect to the RDS in [AZ-1]coz its already a Multi-AZ, So wanted to have the fault tolerance set up only for the Web server. I was able to install WordPress on AZ-2 public subnet, but I was unable to connect to the 
   RDS[MYSQL]endpoint in AZ-1.

Getting the error message.

"Already installed.You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Already installed.You appear to have already installed WordPress. To
>   reinstall please clear your old database tables first".

This means your second web server can successfully connect to the RDS instance. Instead of trying to "install" WordPress, just copy all your WordPress files from the first web server and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks for responding. I have a question.Can I request an explanation for your answer? 
What difference does copy make from installing? Why does the error message "already installed "pops up only during installation and doesn't happen when we copy the same files.

Comment: If you copy the files from your first server, they won't contain setup scripts and will contain `wp-config.php` with correct settings.